# How to access boot menu on a Lenovo G500s

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo G500s laptop which comes with FreeDOS installed. I want to install Windows, but I am not able to enter the boot menu so I can boot from a DVD.

I have tried keys like <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, etc.

How can I get to the boot menu?

Answer (score 11):

Use <kbd>F12</kbd> for Bootmenu. Please remember press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to make it work.

If all do not work, make sure your keyboard is functional or try a external USB keyboard to check.

To install Windows
 - insert Windwows DVD
 - Boot from disk
 - install as instructed

On the Lenovo G500S you will have to push the little button next to the power button while the laptop is turned off or asleep, to enter the BIOS and boot menu. You can change the boot sequence by entering the BIOS and in there make the dvd-player the first boot device.

Comment: I have hp 2230tx laptop and kingston dtse9 pendrive. I am not able to reach startup menu with this pendrive plugged in, which is making me not install new windows 10. How can I reach startup menu?

Answer (score 3):

Some Lenovo laptops have a second button next to the power button. Instead of pressing the function keys you actually have to *just* press the second button which has a u-turn arrow on it; it will give you a list of options (Bios, Boot menu, normal boot). I was also trying to press `F2`, `F10` and also trying with the `FN` button without success.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off/ shutdown your Lenovo notebook and then press/ hold the "Novo-Button"[image] which is (usually) always next to the power button

[image]